# Unable to see calender control properly

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using z index and position : absoulte , im unable to display calender control comopletely . shwing partiall. due to its coming behind of button control. attached image  [image: screen shot of design issue]

```
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User :" ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDlUsers" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="false"  Width="180px">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<asp:Label ID="LblProject" runat="server" Text="Project :"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlProject" runat="server"  Width="180px"></asp:DropDownList>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<asp:Label ID="date" runat="server" Text="Date :"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Visible="True"  ToolTip="hello" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtdate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ValidationGroup="validate" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate">
                   </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                </td>

</tr>


</table>
</div>

<div>
 <asp:Button Style="z-index: 102; left: 580px; position: absolute;
        top: 210px"  Width="100px" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" 
        onclick="BtnSearch_Click" ValidationGroup="validate" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can apply different colors for both search button and calendarcontrol.
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added style in head which resolved my issue

```
<style type="text/css">
   .ajax__calendar_container { z-index : 1000 ; }
</style>
```